# What is the legality of Police Union "Get Out of Jail Free Cards"?

Tags: criminal-law, police

**Background**
I recently read an [article](https://www.vice.com/en/article/v7gxa4/pba-card-police-courtesy-cards) about donators and friends of police unions being given passes, which allows them to be let off of the hook for small crimes, such as traffic tickets.

**Questions**
What is the legality of these passes? Can police unions be charged for corruption or fraud? What is the role of an individual officer in a case like this? Are any cities actively fighting these police unions in court?

Comment: The PBA ['Get Out of Jail Free' cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Out_of_Jail_Free_card) is a pun for the 2 Chance and Community Chest cards used in the game [Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)) that have existed at least since at least 1935 and have no legal effect.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, can it be shown that they do influence a significant number of policemen? Then the lack of legal effect is besides the point, it is their illegal effect which matters.

Comment: @o.m. The OP is asking about the **Legality**. Both those who use it (the card holder) and those that accepts it (the police) could be found guilty of some form of **undue influence**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, the way I read the OP it is about the question if "selling" those things is corruption, i.e. illegal.

Comment: @o.m The whole concept of the card (with the words 'Special treatment') contradicts the concept of [Equality before the law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_before_the_law). As you pointed out in your answer, it is at least *unethical* for the issuers. Their lawyers will claim that 'only PBA events' are meant. The selling of such a card as a collectors item will not be illegal. The **usage** of the card to avoid a punishment stipulated by the law will be illegal.

Comment: I agree that those using the card should also be charged with a criminal offense.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, is the use of the card attempted bribery or attempted provision of a "character witness" by the offender? The former is illegal, the latter is legal but should be futile at this point. A cop who lets himself be influenced by that card is corrupt, but he can always claim there were different reasons.

Comment: @o.m In a functioning justice system, it is the **task of the judge** to determine the **intent** of the card usage. If the card receiver/buyer *intent* is solely to add the card to a album collection then this is not illegal. The **attempt** to use the card to avoid charges/prosecution, then that person's *intent* to commit an illegal activity is clear. If successful, the police officer that allowed this should also be charged and removed from such a position. All part of the **due process**. Consequences for the card issuer should then also be taken into consideration to avoid further misuse

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it apart:

- The police has an union or charity.
  That's legal in most jurisdictions.
- The union or charity accepts donations from non-police.
  Also legal in most jurisdictions.
- The union communicates who the donors are.
  Generally legal in most jurisdictions. Keeping it secret would be just as problematic.
- Police officers have some discretion if and how they charge incidents.
  That's just common sense. Otherwise you get cases like 8-year-olds being arrested. (You get those anyway when the police don't use their discretion, or if the laws are too rigid.)
- Police officers let themselves be influenced by the donor card in how they apply their discretion.
  That's usually illegal on the part of the *police officer*. The Brits use the catchphrase 'without fear or favour.' But it is difficult to prove, even if it is systematic.
- The union issues *donor cards* to facilitate the effects of the previous bullet point.
  That sounds at the very least *unethical*. Some might argue that it is organized corruption.

On the other hand, you can assume that the police unions have some decent lawyers on staff, and that they made sure that the words on their cards are not blatantly illegal in the jurisdiction in question.

It might take something like a whistleblower, a sting operation, or an internal affairs investigation to prove corruption.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. Officer discretion can only apply when the conditions and situations are different when somebody is accused of a crime, like a traffic ticket. The 14th amendment's equal protection clause states that all citizens should be given the same protection under the law. If 2 people were speeding down a road at the same time, and one had a PBA card, shouldn't both be given the same punishment?

Comment: @DapperDuck, of course they should get the same punishment in the same situation. But it is *never* quite the same situation with different people. So it will be hard to prove that it was the PBA card which made the difference and not, say, the belligerent response by one motorist.

Comment: Yep.   The situation read like asking if "professional curtosey" among officers is illegal (i.e. A cop pulls a car over.   A guy in the car is an off duty cop from another police force (not always the driver).  The initiating cop lets the driver off with a warning instead of giving a ticket.).   Again, it's not illegal and it doesn't always happen to work out, but they tend to let them go more than not.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -5):

The typical situation is that a supporter of the Police Benevolent Association can get a card, which says something like "The bearer of this card is a supporter of the PBA and you should try to extend every courtesy possible". This is entirely legal and is not corrupt or fraudulent. Law enforcement officers can exercise discretion in enforcing the law – there is, presently, no requirement that everyone who goes 1 mile over the limit be prosecuted to the full extent of the law. Unlike an HOV pass which is a contractual guarantee that you will not get fined for driving in the leftmost lane, a PBA courtesy card is not "enforceable". This is not to say that the landscape could not change in the future, by limiting officer discretion. At present, these card are legal.

Comment: -1 for not corrupt, otherwise a decent answer.

Comment: -1 for ignoring the Equal Protection Clause.